# Openlayers 3 + Use React to display vector features

Tags: reactjs, openlayers-3

I am using openlayers in a React based JS app. I have a vector layer that has different color according to a field given from the server.

Is it possible to use react for drawing the icons on the map? or should I use simple openlayers object with simple plain javascript?

Regards, Ido

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "drawing icons". Actual (image) icons for existing features, drawing the features themselves, filling popovers or providing feature data to the map?

Comment: I can use openlayers' style function and use plain simple JS. I am asking If I can use React componentns instead.

Comment: What do you want the components to do?

Comment: Render a component differently based on logic

Answer (score 0):

One year later, I created this minimal wrapper
[react-openlayers](https://github.com/allenhwkim/react-openlayers).

It is a minimal [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) 
wrapper of [OpenLayer 3+](https://openlayers.org/)
written in [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)

You may copy/paste code from there.